# How do i replace the sidebar to use pages instead of blogs?

Tags: sidebar

I want to use wordpress as a CMS and not as a blog. I am using the default twentyeleven theme and i would like to remove 'archive' (the blog ToC) and 'Meta' (login) and replace it with a sidebar seen on a traditional site. The part i am having trouble is how do i do it in a way were i can add pages to the sidebar from within the admin area rather then hardcoding in php?

I also would like it to be in the format below where the heading is not clickable and the entries i can add/remove from the admin area.

## About

person one
person two

## Services

Service A
Service B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative method to what @Tanmoy gave above is to make an additional navigation menu (Appearance - Menus) and call it something like Sidebar-Pages.

Then you can add the headers with a "link" like #. Add the sub-pages you want and save when you're done.

Then go to widgets (Appearance - Widgets) and there you will see a widget called "Custom Menu". Drag that into Main Sidebar and select the menu you just created.

Comment: Hmm, ok so i added the 'headers' via `Custom Links` with the link being `#`. How might i use css to make it look like a heading? I looked at the html made then i looked around that page and i am clueless on how i can make it look like a heading

Comment: you have a URL I can have a look at? If not, you can add a CSS-class to each item in your menu. If you don't see it at first, then you open up Screen Options and enable it first.

Answer (score 1):

To place a list of pages in sidebar, just go to *Appearance > Widget* from WordPress admin area, and drag the "Pages" widget to any of the sidebar you want. In case of 2011, that should me "Main Sidebar".

To get non-clickable heading, just create a page template.

Comment: I figured out how to make a page template (i see it in `/wp-admin/theme-editor.php`) however i cant figure out how to add it into the menu